# Loop through entries in a list and create new list

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I have a list of strings that looks like that

```
name=['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam','Henry',.......]
```

I want to create a newlist with the logic shown below. I want to go to every entry in name and assign it a number if the entry is seen for the first time. If it is being repeated(as in the case with 'Sam') I want to assign it the corresponding number, include it in my newlist and continue.

```
newlist = []
name[1] = 'Jack'
Jack = 1 
newlist = ['Jack']
name[2] = 'Sam'
Sam = 2 
newlist = ['Jack','Sam']
name[3] = 'Terry'
Terry = 3 
newlist = ['Jack','Sam','Terry']
name[4] = 'Sam'
Sam = 2 
newlist = ['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam']
name[5] = 'Henry'
Henry = 5 
newlist = ['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam','Henry']
```

I know this can be done with something like

```
u,index = np.unique(name,return_inverse=True)
```

but for me it is important to loop through the individual entries of the list name and keep the logic above. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: So basically you'd want a dictionary....

Comment: Why are you setting each name to an integer value? What is that for and what does it correspond to?

Comment: as far as I understand, a dictionary is not an ordered set, and for me it is important to keep the order as shown

Comment: The integer value corresponds to something like ownership information. So, Jack is owner 1 in this case , sam is owner 2 , etc

Comment: It's better if you work with `dict` ..

Comment: @EliDimitrova - Check my solution. IMO it gives exactly what you asked for with ordering

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If the dictionary must be in the proper order (which shouldn't matter as they are accessed by key anyway) you could try using an [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (Python 2.7 +)

Comment: See my edit, I proposed an alternative solution to keep them in the order in which they appear while still using a dictionary. It swaps the key/value of the dict and checks for duplicates using a different criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `dict` and checking if keys are already paired to a value:

```
name = ['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam','Henry']
vals = {}
i = 0
for entry in name:
    if entry not in vals:
        vals[entry] = i + 1
    i += 1
print vals
```

Result:

`{'Henry': 5, 'Jack': 1, 'Sam': 2, 'Terry': 3}`

Elements can be accessed by "index" (read: key) just like you would do for a list, except the "index" is whatever the `key` is; in this case, the keys are names.

```
>>> vals['Henry']
5
```

**EDIT**: If order is important, you can enter the items into the `dict` using the *number* as the key: in this way, you will know which owner is which based on their number:

```
name = ['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam','Henry']
vals = {}
i = 0
for entry in name:
    #Check if entry is a repeat
    if entry not in name[0:i]:
        vals[i + 1] = entry
    i += 1  
print (vals)
print (vals[5])
```

This code uses the order in which they *appear* as the key. To make sure we don't overwrite or create duplicates, it checks if the current name has appeared before in the list (anywhere from 0 up to `i`, the current index in the `name` list).

In this way, it is still in the "sorted order" which you want. Instead of accessing items by the name of the owner you simply index by their number. This will give you the order you desire from your example.

Result:

```
>>> vals
{1: 'Jack', 2: 'Sam', 3: 'Terry', 5: 'Henry'}
>>> vals[5]
'Henry'
```

Comment: This will not keep order as indicated (e.g. Sam is squashed).

Comment: I didn't notice that the order he defines skipped number 4 (ie, second appearance of Sam). Edited code to reflect how to do this. If this is what you meant by squashed, I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since order is important to you. Use [`orderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the `collections` module.

Use a dictionary. Iterate over your list with a `for` loop and then check to see if you have the name in the dictionary with a `if` statement. `enumerate` gives you the index number of your name, but keep in mind that index number start from `0` so in accordance to your question we append 1 to the index number giving it the illusion that we begin indexing from `1`

```
import collections

nl = ['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam','Henry']

d = collections.OrderedDict()

for i,n in enumerate(nl):
    if n not in d:
        d[n] = [i+1]

print d
```

Output:

`OrderedDict([('Jack', [1]), ('Sam', [2]), ('Terry', [3]), ('Henry', [5])])`

**EDIT:**

The ordered dict is still a dictionary. So you can use `.items()` to get the key value pairs as tuples. the number is essectially a list so you can do this:

```
for i in d.items():
    print '{} = {}'.format(i[0],i[1][0]) #where `i[1]` gives you the number at that position in the tuple, then the `[0]` gives you the first element of the list.
```

Output:

```
Jack = 1
Sam = 2
Terry = 3
Henry = 5
```

Comment: Dear letsc, thank you very much for your answer. How can I access the numbers [1], [2], [3], [5] ? For me it is important after every iteration to get the numbers because I am using them for further calculation

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create variable.By using globals() I am creating global variable .If you want you can create local variable using locals()

Usage of globals()/locals() create a dictionary which is the look up table of the variable and their values by adding key and value you are creating a variable

```
lists1 = ['Jack','Sam','Terry','Sam','Henry']

var = globals()

for i,n in enumerate(nl,1):
    if n not in var:
        var[n] = [i]

print var

{'Jack':1,'Sam': 2,'Terry': 3, 'Henry':5}

print Jack

1
```

Answer (score 0):

If order of the original list is key, may I suggest two data structures, a dictionary and a newlist

```
d = {}
newlist = []
for i,n in enumerate(nl):
    if n not in d:
        d[n] = [i+1]
    newlist.append({n: d[n]})
```

newlist will return

```
[{'Jack': [1]}, {'Sam': [2]}, {'Terry': [3]}, {'Sam': [2]}, {'Henry': [5]}]
```

to walk it:

```
for names in newlist:
    for k, v in names.iteritems():
        print('{} is number {}'.format(k, v))
```

NOTE:  This does not make it easy to lookup the number based on the name as other suggested above.   That would require more data structure logic.  This does however let you keep the original list order, but keep track of the time the name was first found essentially.